# Accessing a LocalDB database only with username and password

Tags: localdb

I have an application which uses LocalDB. I would like this database to be protected with at least a password. Nobody should access the data without knowing the password.

I have tried creating a login into database but, anyone can still access inside by using Windows Authentication easily.

Target machine doesn't have SQL Server Management Studio, so I should keep everything portable in the database file (.mdf .ldf)

Comment: same problem :(

Comment: @AhmedSuror and Ahmet Did u find solution ?. If you do please answer

Comment: @Baganaakh Unfortunately, most people are talking about using **user accounts** to get rid of this issue :(

Comment: I couldn't find a solution Bagaaakh